# Smpp Server How to configure Vsmppbox SMPP Server with fake DLR reports?

Tags: kannel, opensmppbox

How to enable Fake DLR in Vsmppbox SMPP Server

```
group=vsmppbox
id=VSMPPBOX
log-file=/var/log/kannel/vsmppbox.log
log-level=0
smpp-port=4721
database-type=mysql
database-config=mysql
database-enable-queue=1
inbound-queue-threads=4
outbound-queue-threads=4
auth-method=1
database-user-table=smpp_users
database-store-table=smpp_store
database-log-table=smpp_log
database-pdu-table=smpp_queued_pdu
database-route-table=smpp_route
database-ndnc-table=smpp_ndnc
database-spam-table=smpp_spam
database-template-table=smpp_template
database-sender-table=smpp_sender
database-version-table=smpp_version
```

This is the minimum configuration im using in vsmppbox group and its working great with current settings on very higher load

Comment: Now VSMPPBOX structure changed new features added like automatic DLR update in MT table for easy Log reports, MO,MT,DLR on seperate tables, Sender,receiver based routing and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fake DLR is enabled by default in Vsmppbox,
To generate Delivered and Failed reports you have to add values in `simulate_deliver_every` and `simulate_permanent_failure_every` fields in smpp user table